# VSCode on MacOS (Ventura) "open" folder finder dialogue does not show full path. Why not?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, absolute-path

When I open a normal finder window on MacOS (Ventura),  I have it set so that I can see the absolute path listed at the bottom of the window.   This does NOT happen in VSCode.  When clicking Open (or menu file/open)  I am always wondering if I might be opening in a similar path.. but I don't know, because the dialogue does not tell me where I am! .. and I don't want to have to click on the folder window at the top! to find out!) How can I change VSCode finder behavior so it is the same as normal system finder?

I tried looking for settings in JSON file.. but can't find an option that covers this behavior.  I don't understand why anyone would NOT want to see file path information.  I ALWAYS want to know at a glance where I am in the file system!  I want the full path!  My expectation is that for such a sophisticated and elegant Code editor and environment,  one should always be able to easily see  the FULL absolute path you are in.
My regular finder shows the full path. Why is it missing in VSCode?

[image: VSCode Open finder window]

[image: My system finder window]

Comment: "Research effort"???? What research effort?  Do you want a picture?   I couldn't find ANY entry in stack-Overflow on this topic.. and General google searches do not bring anything up either!  What other "research" can I do?

Comment: More importantly, WHY is it that know one knows the answer to this very simple question? It seems like a perfectly reasonable query?  I added images to make this question a clear one.

Comment: when exactly will you use the absolute path?

Comment: When I want to know exactly WHERE I am in the local path on my device!   If I have multiple folders... lets say I have multiple "images" folders.. or multiple folders named "styles" or "scripts" because I might be working on several website projects which typically have folders with that name.   What if i'd like to be SURE .. just with a glance that I am navigating in the correct folder system.  I should not have to click anything to discern that information. The full path should ALWAYS be visible when working in software production environments.

Answer (score 0):

An Open panel is not the same as a Finder window.  If you click the pop up menu in the top middle of the open panel, it will show the path to the folder being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you `hold option`, the path will display at bottom like a popup.

[check this](https://support.apple.com/zh-cn/guide/mac-help/mchlp1774/mac) or google `mac os show file path`
[image: hold option]